# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu becomes transparent when Navbar Height is increased

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, background, navbar

I am not very experienced but I sure am good at finding problems.
My bootstrap navbar needs to be 150px in height to hold a larger logo image. When I put the height component in the CSS and resize the window for under 767 px, the dropdown menu loses the background color and becomes transparent--making the words/links impossible to see. If I remove the height from the CSS the menu comes back but it isn't the right height. I've banged my head for hours on this and need some ideas. You can see it at http://www.ashlandlockandsafe.com/index3.html (resize the window to see the problem).

```
    .navbar { 
    background:#2D5F84;
    height:155px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
     }
```

This is the rest of the CSS (I have adjusted all of the navbar commented template CSS accordingly with adjusting the height of the navbar.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.well {
    font-size:2.5em;
    text-align:center;
    text:#000;
    padding:0;
    border:#000 solid 4px;
    background-image:url(../images/metal.png);
    background-image:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;


}
h1 {text-align:center;


}
.phonetxt {
    font-size:36px;
    text-align:center;
}

}
body {
    padding-top: 150px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top.         Change  if height of navigation changes. */
background-image:url(../images/brushedsilverback.jpg);
}

.navbar-fixed-top .nav {
padding: 60px 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
padding: 0 15px;
}

footer {
padding: 30px 0;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    body {
    padding-top: 150px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top.     
 Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    padding: 13px 0;
}
 .well {
    font-size:2em;
    text-align:center;
    border:#000 solid 2px;
    border-radius:0;
    text:#000;
    background-image:url(../images/metal.png);
    background-image:no-repeat;
    padding:2 0;
    }

    h1 {font-family:"arial";
        font-size:17px;
        font-weight:700;
    }

  }

@media(min-width:925px) {
    body {
    padding-top: 150px; /* Required padding for .navbar-      fixed-top.        Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
 .well {
    font-size:1.6em;
    text-align:center;
    text:#000;
    border:#000 solid 1px;
    border-radius:0;
    background-image:url(../images/metalsmall.png);
    background-image:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center
    padding:0;

    }
h1 {font-family:"arial";
        font-size:17px;
        font-weight:700;
    }
```

Comment: The navbar maintains it blue background (#2D5F84) when resized to mobile width for me Linda.

Comment: Andrew, the Navbar retains the color but does the dropdown menu?

Comment: hmm. yes that's true. Sorry about that. I just checked the navbar, not the dropdown. Hold on, let me check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the height from the `.navbar` div and add it to `navbar-header` instead like this:

```
.navbar-header {
    height:155px;
}
```

Comment: Do mark this as the right answer if it helped you in solving the issue Linda :)

Comment: can I ask you another question or do I have to make a new post? If I can, when the navbar collapse starts in the 768px-992px range and the menu words go under the logo, the navbar now expands about 60 pixels in height more than I want. I uploaded the file to the same link....thanks!

Comment: Can you please add it as a new question so others can check it out too :) I'm checking it from my side too now

Comment: Just change the height value in your query from 150px to 125px like this: @media screen and (max-width: 767px)
.navbar-header {
    height: 125px;
}

Comment: Or even lesser depending on what you want.

Comment: I already tried that in the query and it removed the menu icon for the lower screen res query. I'll do some research, clean it all up, and post a new question if I can't beat it into submission.

Comment: removed the menu icon? It shouldn't do that. That's weird.